# Adding fixed background image and scrolling front div to an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add the fixed background to html page using css which have scrolling front div. But after doing this my JavaScript form not gets loaded. but when I remove that image and clear the css everything works well,

style.css after adding bg image:

```
html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
background: url('../images/bg.png') no-repeat center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}

body{
}
.wrap {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

But when I clear it everything works well,

```
html{
}
body{
}
.wrap {
}
```

Please see attached images,

[image: a]

and

[image]

Comment: Please include your HTML code and/or a demo fiddle.

Comment: the site is actually http://m.tastecards.com I commented the css for html and body..

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: fixed;
```

instead of

```
position: fixed;
```

EDIT: Although Im not sure I understand your question entirely.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add a background image, but remove the background color for the scrolling div?

Comment: I mean to say after adding background image the page doesn't load the form completely.. see second image